# mysql timestamp compare date string

Tags: mysql, datetime, select, timestamp

we have a store procedure, the IN parameter is DATE today. in this procedure, a aql is to compare this today value with a table which has a timestamp column.
for example:

```
column A
2012-12-01 00:00:00
```

SQL:

```
select * from t where A = today.
```

We run this procedure in phpmyadmin, it run OK. but it's not work in command line.

Why?

Comment: What exactly does the query look like and what exactly doesn't work how?

Answer (score 4):

Guess you may need to format both dates into a common format.. To be safe you may even add `Date()` or `str_to_Date` if required...if you are not sure column `A` contains a proper date...

Try this please:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A, '%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(TODAY, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

if you meant `CURDATE()` by `today` then try this as well,

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A, '%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: I would upvote this a thousand times if I could. you just saved me from a nightmare that haunted me yesterday. seriously

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the dates are in different formats and that's causing them to be not equal. You can use `datediff(date1, date2) = 0` to fix this.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp